# Passing Props (img url ) using React-Modal || TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapping, bootstrap-modal

When I try to run this code it gives me this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

This code should return the image modal but throwing an error. I don't get it why I'm getting this error in the mapping function.

Is it my deps array is empty before the API call so using deps.map will cause the error? Or the cookie problems?

**DepositRecord.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Button, ButtonToolbar, Table } from "react-bootstrap";
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';
import AddDepositModal from "./AddDeposiModal";

const DepositRecord = () => {
  const [deps, setDeps] = useState([]);
  const [visibleModal, setVisibleModal] = useState(false);
  const [depImage, setDepImage] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
    loadDepsHandler();
    }, []);

  const loadDepsHandler = () => {
    const myRequest = new Request("https://XXXXXXXXXX/DepositRecords", {
      method: "GET",
      cache: "default",
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${cookies.get('userToken')}` },
    });
    debugger;
    fetch(myRequest)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        const { results } = data;
        setDeps(results);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };

  const setDepHandler = (id) => {
    const dep = deps.find((a) => a.id.value === id);
    debugger;
    setDepImage(dep.picture.large);
    setVisibleModal(true);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Customer's Deposit Record</h3>
      <br />

      <Table className="mt-4" striped bordered hover size="sm">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Deposit id</th>
            <th>user name</th>
            <th>img attachment</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {deps.map((item) => (
            <tr key={item.id.name}>
              <td>{item.id.name}</td>
              <td>{item.value}</td>
              <td>
                <ButtonToolbar>
                  <Button
                    variant="primary"
                    onClick={() => setDepHandler(item.id.value)}
                  >
                    image attachment
                  </Button>
                </ButtonToolbar>
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
      {visibleModal && (
        <AddDepositModal
          show={visibleModal}
          onHide={() => setVisibleModal(false)}
          image={depImage}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default DepositRecord;
```

**AddDepositModal.js**

```
import React from "react";
 import { Button, Modal } from "react-bootstrap";

 const AddDepositModal = ({ show, onHide, image }) => {
  return (
    <Modal show={show} onHide={onHide}>
      <Modal.Header closeButton>
        <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
          Deposit Record
        </Modal.Title>
      </Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Body>
        <img src={image} width={700} height={1100} alt={image} />
      </Modal.Body>
      <Modal.Footer>
        <Button variant="danger" onClick={onHide}>
          Close
        </Button>
      </Modal.Footer>
    </Modal>
  );
};
export default AddDepositModal;
```

Comment: `.then((res) => res.json()) .then((data) => { console.log(data) })` what do you get?

Comment: Failed to compile.

Answer (score 0):

First check your array then map through it :

```
       <tbody>
      {deps.length > 0 && deps.map((item) => (
        <tr key={item.id.name}>
          <td>{item.id.name}</td>
          <td>{item.value}</td>
          <td>
            <ButtonToolbar>
              <Button
                variant="primary"
                onClick={() => setDepHandler(item.id.value)}
              >
                image attachment
              </Button>
            </ButtonToolbar>
          </td>
        </tr>
      ))}
    </tbody>
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

Comment: first, console.log your result like this make sure you get data in array form!
  const loadDepsHandler = () => {
    const myRequest = new Request("https://XXXXXXXXXX/DepositRecords", {
      method: "GET",
      cache: "default",
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${cookies.get('userToken')}` },
    });
    debugger;
    fetch(myRequest)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        const { results } = data;
        console.log(results)
        setDeps(results);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };`  

 `

Comment: cannot get the array data from Fetch method !!! I think it is my Authorization: XXXX problem

Comment: I follow this link's solution is work before I adding headers: { Authorization: Bearer ${cookies.get('userToken')}
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70692322/passing-props-img-url-using-react-modal-react-js/70692811#70692811

Comment: use the error also indicates that there is no data so once you get data you can map through it like i answered.you can also check your request status through browser see which kind of status do you have it can help you to fix the bug.